# Does BestMatch V still have performance issues with Natlink in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking, speech-recognition

http://explosionduck.com/wp/introduction-to-voice-programming-part-one-dns-natlink/ says:

> BestMatch V has performance issues with Natlink.

The article was written over two years ago, and the writer uses  Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5.

Does BestMatch V still have performance issues with Natlink in the newer versions of Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Comment: I assume you are still using NaturallySpeaking 12.5?

Comment: @Ramhound yes~~

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It's not an opinion based question, and maybe your question has been downvoted because someone is supporting "Monica Cellio" case, like that all the stackexchange sites will lose their users quickly.

Comment: +1 to remove the downvote made by another person

Comment: Closer voters are definitely not users of dragon naturally speaking.

Comment: There are 2 closer votes and 3 reopen votes... so why isn't this question being reopened?